# Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks, synchronization

I'm new to Microsoft Sync Framework and had been studying lot about it.But I'm unable to get any sample windows application which uses this framework. Can you please help me in getting a sample application? Windows application with a form which contains grid view and just display data, Edit and Save. I have the SDK.

Comment: Have you had a look at this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: It's irrelevant whether it's a console app or not, this will show you how to get it working. Have you tried getting it to get it to work first, before making it 'pretty' with a UI?

Comment: I need to sync from an application not from two different database in sql server

Comment: You cannot sync data directly from a form to a database. In order for the Sync Framework to work data sources needs to be provisioned which means it creates some extra tables in the databases to be sync'ed. These tables contains information about changes made to the database when saving/deleting the data in the database. When you initiate the sync via the sync framework, it invokes some fancy logic that uses the information in these created tables to identify the data that needs to be synchronized. For all of that to work you first need to save the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
https://github.com/Mimetis/SyncWinRT/wiki/01-Setup-your-sync-scenario-:-Server-and-Client

Don't get confused - it is still the Microsoft Sync Framework, but Mimetis ported it to Windows Universal Platform, Android and iOS as well and added a SQLite provider.

And: it contains a very good tutorial and sample that does exactly what you requested.
Hope that helps